# Remote schema stitching with latest versions of Apollo and GraphQL tools

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

i'm having a hard time figuring out the problem with my setup. I have been looking at the documentations but between apollo and graphql-tools the APIs changed frequently.

When i run this script, the console says "Error: Query root type must be provided."

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server";
import { loadSchema } from "@graphql-tools/load";
import { UrlLoader } from "@graphql-tools/url-loader";
import { stitchSchemas } from "@graphql-tools/stitch";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({ path: "../.env" });

async function startServer() {
  const shopifySchema = await loadSchema(process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_URL, {
    loaders: [new UrlLoader()],
    headers: {
      "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token":
        process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN,
    },
    fetch,
  });

  const contentfulSchema = await loadSchema(process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_URL, {
    loaders: [new UrlLoader()],
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    fetch,
  });

  const gatewaySchema = stitchSchemas({
    subschemas: [{ schema: shopifySchema }, { schema: contentfulSchema }],
  });

  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema: gatewaySchema });

  return await server.listen();
}

startServer().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

These are my dependencies:

```json
{
    "@graphql-tools/load": "^7.3.2",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^8.2.0",
    "@graphql-tools/stitch": "^8.3.1",
    "@graphql-tools/url-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "apollo-server": "^3.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.6.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Anyone knows what could be wrong with this?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i have found out that my url endpoints were just incorrect.
I'll leave the question open in case might be useful to someone.

Comment: Hello, you can mark this answer as accepted if this solved for you and the question will still open to others to see this content anyway.. also you can edit and post the details of how you solved it (code/actions/etc)